# Where to put my custom.xsl for my List View's XslLink?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin, visual-studio-2012

I'm in the process of creating my first **App for SharePoint 2013** and after following [this tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp142379.aspx) (using Visual Studio 2012), I now wish to create a custom XSLT file and apply it to my `TestCustomList`'s default view. I have changed the Schema.xml file to read:

```
...
  <View BaseViewID="1" Type="HTML" WebPartZoneID="Main" DefaultView="TRUE" ... Url="AllItems.aspx">
    <XslLink Default="TRUE">custom.xsl</XslLink>
...
```

But I do not know where to put my newly created `custom.xsl`... I don't see how anything in my project relates to the `_layouts` directory on the server.

Answer (score 3):

Your xsl file should be located here:

```
c:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\XSL\
```

To map your xsl file to this folder you need to create Sharepoint Mapped Folder.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231521%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) is explanation how to do that.

Comment: Thanks, but step 3 says to create a *SharePoint 2013 Visual Web Part* but I am creating an *App for SharePoint 2013* (under Visual C# > Office/SharePoint > Apps) are there instructions for an App?

Comment: Also, the menu item in step 6 doesn't exist (I'm guessing that's because the project type is different?)